# Failed to connect to proxy URL when deploying CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-vpc

I am attempting to deploy a CloudFormation template, but the Internet Gateway resource fails with an encoded error that [decodes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/decode-authorization-message.html) to:

```
Failed to connect to proxy URL: "http://127.0.0.1:10080"
```

What proxy am I missing that would prevent an Internet Gateway from being created?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the proxy error is misleading. The real issue is that the user deploying the CloudFormation template did not have the correct permissions.

I granted the user the `AmazonVPCFullAccess` policy, and the template was deployed correctly.